# How to save template craeted by Digital Persona into database through Java

Tags: java, database, templates, save

I am using Digital Persona to create an authenticating application in Java. Actually I am enrolling and verifying the Template created, but I want to save the finger print template data into database and then retrieve that from database and compare while verifying.

So is there any way or technique to store the template data in mysql database and then retrieve it.

Kindly reply whoever knows any thing.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

you can read from SDK manual that you can serialize template set to byte() data type. 
And then you can save to mysql blob type